# Websocket as a platform-independent protocol?

Tags: websocket, protocols

I'm newbie in web application development and protocols.
I'm developing a Java-EE web application that uses the Websocket java API, but the client is a C++ application with its own API written in C++.

I want to exchange the data by using JSON, do I need to implement my own API in C++ Language to be used by the client or can I just send the data from java and receive it by C++ so that each one can use its own API?

Comment: can you elaborate more please.
do you say that there's no need to re-implement my logic again in C++?

Comment: There are many existing libraries for the client server itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-or-c-websocket-server-library , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/733297/WebSocket-libraries-comparison , https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp , http://ahoj.io/libwebsockets-simple-http-server **etc**

Comment: Both JSON and Websocket/HTTP libraries can be found readily for both Java and C++. The two different parts (Java and C++) will need to additionally support an *application-level protocol*. There may be projects to proxy one layer directly onto the other (e.g. [C++] FFI over a [WS/JSON] RPC), or whatnot: however, I suspect these are rare. There will probably be more immediate success looking up a technology like COM+/CORBA/ICE or even RMI.

Comment: WAMP (http://wamp.ws/) is a WebSocket based application-level protocol with implementations in several languages-